# How do you make a specific part of an object smooth?

Tags: modeling, smooth

I'm very new to Blender but I didn't know where to ask questions, hopefully this works :). I'm following a tutorial on how to make an apple, and it was all going great until I got to the stem.
[image: my apple]

As you can see my stem is very blocky and not smooth. As the tutorial was making it, there was a smooth version of it under the transparent blocky part in Edit Mode. I've tried smoothing it again and even applied the scale but it didn't work.

Here is the tutorial I used.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPKvFGsrgrg&t=227s

It's probably a very easy answer but I would really appreciate some help :)

P.S. Sorry that I don't know all the language to refer to things by.

Comment: if you're talking about the shading, it seems like it is smooth too, if you want it to be smoother you probably need to add topology (i.e subdivide this part)

Comment: You don't have enough geometry for more, but its already smooth, is you want to make it a little rounded, add a subdivision modifier